# Is it possible to calculate the difference between two multi-choice columns?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am trying to create a multi-Choice list of items that reflects the difference between two columns

Column A is a multi-select choice list of items that are needed
Column B is a multi-select Choice list of items that are available
Column C should be a multi-select list of items that are needed but not available.

The list is for simple on-boarding of staff, to identify equipment requirements, to allocate available equipment and produce a list of items that need to be purchased. Open to alternative approaches, or available templates that might provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, there is no OOB way to meet your requiremnt.

Multiple choice column type is not supported in calculated column.